# Sharing session cookie across two named domains

Tags: asp.net, session, security, session-cookies

I have a .net webapplication with the following domains:
www.domain.com
sub.domain.com
files.domain.com

When a user is logged on to domain.com or sub.domain.com, I'd like them to share session state (i.e. be logged into both domains at once). This is possible to do by setting the domain on the session coookie to be ".domain.com".
However, my problem is that the domain "files.domain.com" should *not* have session state due to security issues (xss attacks from user-made files hosted on that domain is an issue).

Is it possible in ASP.NET to use the same asp.net session id for these two domains, but not the third one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options that come to mind:

#1 - Post your login request to both applications via a client side script. This will enable you to set cookies for both valid domains at the same time. This enables you to avoid the XSS issue that you are concerned about by creating cookies for the specific domains that you want to have your users authenticated on.

#2 - Move your "unsecure" site to a different domain. For example: www.domain-files.com. With that option you could use a shared cookie to manage authentication.

Comment: Yeah moving the files domain is of course the way to go, but not sure if I get acceptance for that. Posting login request to both domains I could do, thank you Joe!

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse session cookies and forms authentication cookies. ASP.NET Session cannot be shared between applications. As far as the forms authentication cookie is concerned, well it is just a simple cookie and the way cookies work is by setting the `domain` property.

One way I can think of to achieve this is to define special [machineKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) in `web.config` for the two applications. This way users that authenticated on `www.domain.com` will be emitted a cookie which will be encrypted with the machinekeys of `www.domain.com` and because only `sub.domain.com`  has the same keys will be able to decrypt the cookie. The cookie will still be sent to `files.domain.com` but it won't be able to decrypt it and users won't be authenticated there.

Comment: It's actually the same application, where the two domains point to the same application/server+path. So www.domain.com and sub.domain.com are equal, while files.domain.com point to a different virtual folder of the application. So basically I need the users to be authenticated on both two domains with the same sessionId

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the question is why can people upload files that may contain XSS attacks? if they can do this they may find ways of causing other problems.

The most likely candidate is on your login page have a javascript function that sends the credentials to the other server. so when someoe logs in to one domain the javascript function logs them in to the other domain at the same time.

I agree with joe.liedtke who says move files.domain.com to another domain and avoid the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Sharing asp.net authentication on different apps on different sub-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737303/sharing-asp-net-authentication-on-different-apps-on-different-sub-domains/4737491#4737491)

As mentioned below, only applications with matching machine keys will be able to authenticate with each other. So, assuming files.domain.com is given a different machine key it will be unable to decrypt the session cookie, and there for have no right to the other domains

Comment: Thanks, still not what I'm looking for unfortunately. The browser will still send the cookie, thus enabling e.g. javascriptfiles stored on that domain to intercept cookies - providing an entrypoint for session hijacking on the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it would accomplish your task to store a Guid value in the cookie directly using `Response.Cookies`, then query your database based on that value to get shared authentication information.

Comment: that was what I thought until I realised that a separate cookie could still be used in a XSS attack

Comment: Add a token at the end of the Guid indicating the previous request id.  i.e. a cookie with the value "sessionid={guidvalue}43" when it is the 43rd request.  Then validate the request number.