# Sharing asp.net authentication on different apps on different sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 applications. One on asp.net webforms `main.test.com` which should provide authentication, user logs in and I can use the cookie to authenticate on my asp.net mvc app located at `myApp.test.com`.

All I'd like to do is able to access the cookie so I can get the userId that was stored in it using the `FormsAuthentication`.

They use normal authentication provided by microsoft;

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms domain="test.com" loginUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" requireSSL="false" timeout="45" name=".ASPXAUTH" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
 </authentication>
```

This cookie should be accessible to any submain on test.com right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set your machine keys in each application so they can each decrypt each others data.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Then make sure you have set your cookie name and path the same in each. Job done, an auth ticket generated in either application should span them both
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

**Edit:** Forgot a bit: 
In your web config also set the domain attribute of the httpCookies node to `test.com`

Answer (score 1):

in the form tag add

```
domain=".test.com"
```

Comment: What if I need to just read the cookie from one, I dont want to set it.

Comment: I'm not following do you want to use the same authentication for both sites or different authentication?