# share user login sessions between two React applications?

Tags: reactjs, web, jwt, nestjs

I use the username, Password for authentication of a single react app. I would like for my users to log in once on either of the web apps and not have to log in again if they happen to go to the other. ( similar to how if i login on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) i'm also logged in to youtube and other google sites )
[image]

Comment: I guess you could share cookies between two domains to manage authentication but not sure how secure it is. Take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823003/1368671

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to like how Google does it. When you login at Google (for any service) you are always redirected to https://accounts.google.com/.

On this site the user logins and then receives a long lasting session cookie. Then the user is redirected back to the service where the user may receive a second session cookie just for that service.

When the user tries to login with Service B, then the user is redirected to https://accounts.google.com/ but as the user is already logged in , then he is automatically redirected back to service B, logged in and ready. Then Service B can issue its own session cookie.

Comment: Are there any examples or tutorials out there that you can recommend? Found nothing sadly.

Comment: Most authorization providers supports this out of the box and you get this feature automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking on the concept of microservices architecture here.

What I visualize here is you will need to have

1. Backend Login App ( Any Language of your choice giving out JSON Response) connected with React Login Interface with it.
2. A 2nd React Application having Login API connected to the first Backend Login App validating Login Credentials. If the user is using the same device and is within 30 days Session Expiry period time. They will be redirected to the 2nd React app with logged-in confirmation.
3. Make n number of applications with Login API going to your first Application for authentication and they all can work on the same authentication.

Also few points to keep in mind. I suppose the database will be common for all applications to store the same Login Data. And keep in mind to keep the Backend Server API is secured with credentials to keep Data secure.

Hope this helps...